# Overlapping and Missing Dates in a list of Contract

Tags: lambda, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, flatten, audit

I am auditing thousands of contracts per site location. We found two main problems, there were contracts renewed for one site that is overlapping and apparently there were months in between which doesn't have a valid contract. Overlapping is not allowed because services should be made once per month only, while missing dates or gaps also not allowed because the services must be continuous from the first contract. Below is sample information. Imagine I have this data in thousand, is there a formula or function available that could trigger these issues?

[image]

Comment: Just a comment because I don't have time to write a full answer now, but maybe this will inspire you... A condition to check for overlap between two periods (StartDate1, EndDate1) and (StartDate2, EndDate2) would be to check for whether StartDate1 is between StartDate2 and EndDate2, or StartDate2 between StartDate1 and EndDate1. So if for any given (StartDate, EndDate) you find any other line where this is true, you have an overlap.   Such a check is likely to be quite slow, though, as you're executing basically a n-squared type algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(LAMBDA(aa, bb, IF(""=TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SUBSTITUTE(LAMBDA(x, y, 
 XLOOKUP(x, INDEX(y,,1), INDEX(y,,2),,,1)&XLOOKUP(x, INDEX(y,,1), INDEX(y,,2),,,-1))
 (LAMBDA(a, b, IF(DAYS(b, a)+1<=SEQUENCE(1, MAX(DAYS(b, a))+1, 0),, 
 a+SEQUENCE(1, MAX(DAYS(b, a))+1, 0)))(aa, bb),
 LAMBDA(a, b, SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(DAYS(b, a)+1<=SEQUENCE(1, MAX(DAYS(b, a))+1, 0),, 
 a+SEQUENCE(1, MAX(DAYS(b, a))+1, 0)&"×"&ROW(a))), "×"))(aa, bb)), ROW(aa), )),,9^9))),,"overlap"))
 (A8:INDEX(A:A, MAX((""<>A:A)*ROW(A:A))), B8:INDEX(B:B, MAX((""<>B:B)*ROW(B:B)))))
```

[image: b]

Comment: Thank you very much for this. One last thing please, I would like to add one criteria to find overlap per "Site" basis? We have thousands of sites with multiple contracts in our record. We would like to identify which "sites" has overlapping contracts and missing period.

Comment: @ArchieUni yes it would be possible but I recommend opening a separate question as the "Site" condition was not mentioned in your prior question and implementing this condition to provided answer would require a complete redo of the formula

Comment: thank you @player0. sorry for late response.